# How to save plist as a dictionary with main key? NSDictionary+Plist+ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, plist

I need to create plist dictionary with main key, for instance: @"events". The main dictionary with key will call arrays of data. By now, I am able to create plist but there is no main key/dictionary. This is how I create plist:

```
    NSDictionary *eventsDictionary = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"eventList"];
       NSString *path = [
                              NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject ];
                           path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY_USER_DEFAULTS ];
            [[NSDictionary dictionary] writeToFile:path  atomically:YES ];
```

and my plist:

### My Plist

```
<dict>
<key>eventID</key>
<array/>
<string>111</string>
<string>112</string>
<key>eventName</key>
<array>
<string>AAA</string>
<string>BBB</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

But I want main dictionary key as @"Events":

### Headings

```
<dict>
    <key>Events</key>
    <dict>
    <key>eventID</key>
    <array/>
    <string>111</string>
    <string>112</string>
    <key>eventName</key>
    <array>
    <string>AAA</string>
    <string>BBB</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
```

My plist has only arrays of data without main dictionary, meaning there is a root and arrays of data.

Please suggest any solution. Unfortunately, cannot add any image as I have no enough points :(

Thank you.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to write part of the `eventsDictionary` to the new plist?

Comment: @rmaddy, I can already write all events which are inside of eventsDictionary into plist. My problem is I do not know how to create main dictionary/key inside of the plist. So we I call the main key all arrays of data inside of the dictionary will be called. By now my plist looks like root->eventName(array), eventID(array) etc... But I need, root->eventList(dictionary)->eventName(array), eventID(array) etc... I hope this is clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to place your dictionary into another dictionary. Something like:

```
NSDictionary *eventsDictionary = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"eventList"];
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:eventsDictionary 
                                                      forKey:@"Events"];

NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY_USER_DEFAULTS];

[plistDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: That's what I meant. Great, this works! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Glad that helped. Please select my answer as the correct answer by clicking the check box so that I get the points. Thanks.

Comment: Btw I refactored my answer to remove the use of a mutable dictionary and make it more concise, but it's the same concept.